# Unfortunately, <App name> has stopped working. Android?Eclipse application

Tags: android

I am writting a very simple converter app, it worked fine for sometime on my mobile but then when i disconnected it and reconnected to the laptop it stopped working displaying the above message.

Here's the code:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText editCentimeters = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCent);

        final EditText editInches = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editInch);

        Button buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);

        buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                double Centi = Double.valueOf(editCentimeters.getText().toString());

                double Inches= Centi * 0.3937007 ;

                editInches.setText(String.valueOf(Inches));



            }
        });
    }



}
```

This is the logcat

```
07-23 23:54:42.624: D/dalvikvm(12601): Late-enabling CheckJNI
07-23 23:54:43.745: D/AndroidRuntime(12601): Shutting down VM
07-23 23:54:43.745: W/dalvikvm(12601): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a72228)
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601):    at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601):    ... 11 more
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is? I am new to Android and this is my first app so may be its a very silly mistake i am doing but please explain what the error is and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: post your xml layout.

Comment: `android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText` - it's clear.  You have declared something as a TextView in your XML and are trying to cast it to an `EditText` in your code.

Comment: How to modify that error??

Comment: @SiddharthGupta post your xml. you have a textview in xml while initializing in `onCreate` you are casting with `EditText`. Your exception says it all.

Comment: +1 for asking how we knew what the error was.  Most people copy and paste the answer and blunder into their next exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  final EditText editCentimeters = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCent);
```

line 18 (counted...) this is an TextView in your xml. Change it to EditText

If you made sure its a EditText in your xml. Eclipse -> Project -> clean.

Comment: `07-23 23:54:43.765: E/AndroidRuntime(12601):    at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)` the "MainActivity.java:18" means line 18 of your MainActivity class.

Comment: Its working :D but how did you find that i had to change TextView to EditText?? Sorry. As i said i am new to this so i'd really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText`, When reading logs. Find out whats the exception first. Then see what line is causing it. ClassCastException is when something is casted wrong, at that line: `(EditText)` is casting Somthing to edittext. So I assume the error should be there.